# Efficient way to read text files having irregular formats without using FOR loop in R

Tags: r, loops, text

I have a input file that have the pattern as follow: 
- the first 2 lines contain parameters for the model & month & year: I only need to get month and year from these 2 lines
- the next block contains the actual data: 172 rows and 256 columns
The data goes on N times

[Link to the actual data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tptmj6tkpo5skh/rchData.txt)

Another file is an ArcGIS ascii grid which has the first 6 lines are ArcGIS parameters and a block of 172 rows x 256 columns (equal 1 inside the region, -9999 elsewhere)

[Link to the ArcGIS ascii grid](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jktae6donghny21/arcgisGrid.txt)

What I'd like to do is to read the data and calculate average value for each timestep based on the mask grid. At the moment the only way I can think of is to use 3 nested loops

```
for (i in 1:N) {
   for (j in 1:172) {
      for (k in 1:252) {
           Read the data
           Do calculation
           Write the result out
      }
   }
{
```

Is there any better way to avoid using such complicated FOR loop? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: based on what agstudy suggested and other sources, I read my data line-by-line and use strsplit to get the value. My final code is as follow

```
########################## Read the grid first ########################
con <- file(gisGrid) 
open(con);

# Read the first 6 lines
gisData <- readLines(textConnection(
'ncols         256
nrows         172
xllcorner     730000
yllcorner     227000
cellsize      1320
NODATA_value  -9999'),n=6)

# Extract value
gisPara <- matrix(unlist(strsplit(gisData,' +')), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
summary(gisPara)

# Read the mask grid:
gridValue <- read.table(file = gisGrid, header = FALSE, skip=6)
gridValueVec <- as.vector(as.matrix(gridValue))

close(con)

######################### Read the data file #########################
con <- file(dataFile) 
open(con);

# Define number of timesteps, nRow, nCol
nTime <- 3
nRow <- 172
nCol <- 256

# Read the whole file in
data.lines <- scan(con, what=character(), sep='\n')
data <- NULL
# Create 3D object to store data for each timestep
data$timestep <- list( rep( matrix(nrow=nRow, ncol=nCol), nTime ) )
data$month <- list( rep( nTime ) )
data$year <- list( rep( nTime ) )
data$multiply <- list( rep( nTime ) )

# Loop over all timestep
for (i in 1:nTime) {
  # Read the first 2 lines
  data.lines <- data.lines[-1] # remove line from the dataset

  data.line2 <- strsplit(data.lines[1],' ')
  data$month[[i]] <- data.line2[[1]][24]
  data$year[[i]] <- as.numeric(data.line2[[1]][25])
  data.lines <- data.lines[-1]

  dataRead <- matrix(nrow=nRow, ncol=nCol)
  for(j in 1:nRow) 
  {
    dataRead[j,] <- as.numeric(strsplit(data.lines[1],' ')[[1]])
    data.lines <- data.lines[-1]
  }         

  # Multiply data with the mask grid
  dataReadVector <- as.vector(dataRead)
  gridMultiplication <- ifelse(gridValueVec==-9999, NA,
                               dataReadVector * gridValueVec )

  data$multiply[[i]] <- mean(gridMultiplication, na.rm=TRUE)
  data$timestep[[i]] <- dataRead
}

close(con)
```

Comment: You might want to include the code that you're using for `# Read the data`; the other parts probably aren't relevant, though.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! The code is included!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first File you can use do the following:

Parse the date you read only 2 lines using `readLines`

```
dd <- readLines(
   textConnection('internal  1.0  (free)  -1                 Sep 1990'),n=2)
regmatches(dd,gregexpr('[A-Z][a-z]{2} [0-9]{4}$',dd))[[1]]
"Sep 1990" ## strsplit(...,' ') if you want month/and year separately
```

Then you read the matrix using something like :

```
 read.table(...,skip=2)
```

For the second File , you can use `` `strsplit `` to read the parameters in the file first 6 lines:

```
dd <- readLines(textConnection('ncols         256
nrows         172
xllcorner     730000
yllcorner     227000
cellsize      1320
NODATA_value  -9999
'),n=6)
matrix(unlist(strsplit(dd,' +')),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)

    [,1]           [,2]    
[1,] "ncols"        "256"   
[2,] "nrows"        "172"   
[3,] "xllcorner"    "730000"
[4,] "yllcorner"    "227000"
[5,] "cellsize"     "1320"  
[6,] "NODATA_value" "-9999"
```